# Approach for Debezium in clustered JVM

Tags: debezium

I am using Debezium Embedded Engine and deployed within the JBOSS application (Legacy, Monothilic , Clustered Env) for CDC events on Postgres. We have around 200 tables. Like to hear on approach for configuration of tables across the JVM.

Say  JVM1  - 50 tables, JVM2 - 50 tables , JVM3- 50 tables and JVM4 with 50 tables. Is this right approach?

Comment: I would also want to know the best community practice for the same?

Answer (score 0):

generally I would not recommend to split the processing across multple instances. Only when Debezium would lag behaind the database then it would make sense to do the split.
Multpile Debezium instances mean increase load for database - each of the instance needs its own replication slot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My use case is 50 TPS rate of Database changes. So Enabling connector in one of the JVM should suffice the requirement. Am i right?

Comment: Yes, it should be sufficient. But of course it exactly depends on the average size of the transaction.